# Access php variable in html

Tags: php, html, session-variables

I am using the below php code:

```
<?php 
$str = time().'_'.$_FILES["file1"]["name"];
$fileName = $_FILES["file1"]["name"]; 
$fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["file1"]["tmp_name"]; 
$fileType = $_FILES["file1"]["type"]; 
$fileSize = $_FILES["file1"]["size"]; 
$fileErrorMsg = $_FILES["file1"]["error"]; 

if (!$fileTmpLoc) { 
    echo 'ERROR: Please browse for a file before clicking the upload button.'; 
    exit(); 
} 

if(move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, "upload/" . $str)){ 
    echo "$fileName upload is complete"; 
} else { 
    echo 'move_uploaded_file function failed'; 
}
?>
```

to upload a file on a server. I am altering the filename and keeping it in 
$str. My question is:

When the upload is completed I want to be able in my html file to print a message like

```
You uploaded <?php echo $str; ?>
```

How can I do that? How can I access $str ? Shall I use sessions? Any hint? Thank you a lot in advance...

Comment: Remove space between `<? php`

Comment: Thanks Raptor, I removed it.

Answer (score 3):

Simply store the return value of `move_uploaded_file`

```
$is_uploaded = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, "upload/" . $str);
if($is_uploaded ){ 
   echo "$fileName upload is complete"; 
} else { 
   echo "move_uploaded_file function failed"; 
}
```

in HTML

```
if($is_uploaded ){ 
   echo "<p>You uploaded ".$str."<p>"; 
}
```

Comment: When I add your $is_uploaded... code in my php, the upload breaks and does not work.

Comment: oh sorry i forgot semi colon `move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, "upload/" . $str);`

Comment: Now the upload works (I am sorry too that I didn't notice the absence of semi colon), however now the if part does not seem to work. For example a paste in my html of <?php if($is_uploaded ){ echo "<p>You uploaded ".$str."<p>"; }  ?> gives me the message: "You uploaded ".$str."
"; } ?> " .

Comment: What do you mean i dont understand? Can u show ur html

Comment: <a href="#x" class="overlay" id="go_service"></a>
        <div class="popup">
  <?php if($is_uploaded ){ echo "<p>You uploaded ".$str."<p>"; }  ?>
 </div>

Comment: Is your file in `.php`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62858/discussion-between-meda-and-pebox11).

Comment: Thank you for your courage to chat with me! This shows a great pasture of personality! I can not chat with you right now but only for this I will up vote your answer.

Comment: ok so I will need more details are you posting to the same page?

Answer (score 0):

Local php variables will get deleted or "flushed" when the web browser REFRESHED. To solve this,

- you must use AJAX and return a JSON response to your html file for the successful upload

or

- Store the success or error message on a Session then unset that session after you showed it
  for example

  ```
  <?php
     @session_start();

      //file upload code
      //if success
          $_SESSION['message'] = 'File successfully uploaded';
      //else
          $_SESSION['message'] = 'File upload error';
  ?>
  ```

then into your HTML

```
     <?php @session_start() ?>

     <body>
         <?php if(isset($_SESSION['message']): ?>
                <p><?php echo $_SESSION['message']; ?></p>
                <?php unset($_SESSION['message']) ?>
         <?php endif; ?>
     </body>
```

Comment: I used your direction but with no luck... I am pretty much convinced though that I should use sessions and ajax...

Comment: I just showed you how the structure, not the full code, you have to create the full code yourself

Comment: I did... I will try again... Thanks!

Comment: Good luck, if you can't see a message it means the `$_SESSION['message']` is empty

Comment: have fun experimenting